# Declaración de clases dentro de funciones anónimas

Tags: javascript, three.js

Estoy empezando con [three.js](https://threejs.org/). He conseguido que su ejemplo mínimo funcione correctamente, y ahora quiero añadir un movimiento a la cámara.

Para ello, el propio [three.js](https://threejs.org/) proporciona un *plugin*/ejemplo en `examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js`. Sin embargo, estoy teniendo problemas para usarlo.

Examinando su código, creo que un *destilado* del problema se resume así:

```
class Padre { };

const Namespace = { Padre: Padre };

( function( ) {
  class Hijo extends Namespace.Padre { }
} )( );

const hijo = Hijo( );
```

Esto, probado en node.js, muestra un *bonito* error:

> ReferenceError: `Hijo` is not defined

Lo cual es coherente con el error que obtengo en el navegador:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: `OrbitControls` is not defined

El código real que estoy usando (de momento, un `html` que abro en local mediante `file:///ruta`) es:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <title>Three.js</title>
        <style>
body { margin: 0; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
        <script src='node_modules/three/build/three.js'></script>
        <script src='node_modules/three/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js'></script>
        <script>
const scene = new THREE.Scene( );
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( );

renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

const controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( );
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( cube );

camera.position.z = 5;

function animate( ) {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    // required if controls.enableDamping or controls.autoRotate are set to true
    controls.update();

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
};

animate( );
        </script>
</html>
```

- ¿ Que estoy haciendo mal ?
- ¿ Cómo lo soluciono ?

Comment: ¿Que esperas exactamente? La definición de la clase Hijo la tienes dentro de una función, por lo que su scope va a ser solo dentro de esa función. Fuera de esa función la clase Hijo no existe. El error es bastante claro.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es que no estás importando correctamente `OrbitControls`. Te adjunto un ejemplo con la sentencia `import` que puedes ejecutar desde acá desde SO:

```html
<script type="module">
    import * as THREE from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.121.1/build/three.module.js';
    import { OrbitControls } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.121.1/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';

    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
    const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(cube);

    camera.position.z = 5;

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        // required if controls.enableDamping or controls.autoRotate are set to true
        controls.update();

        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };

    animate();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basta con mirar **TODO** el código de `OrbitControls.js`. Las últimas líneas del archivo son:

```
THREE.MapControls = MapControls;
THREE.OrbitControls = OrbitControls;
```

El módulo se auto-añade el *namespace* `THREE`. Con lo que la solución es, simplemente, usar el nombre totalmente cualificado de la clase:

```
const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
```